# selective replacing of printf statements

Tags: ruby

I am trying to search for a bunch of print statements that I want to filter as follows:

1. I want to select **all dbg_printfs**.
2. Out of all of those I want to select those **that have value.stringValue()**.
3. Out of those I only want those that **do not have value.stringValue().value()**.
4. Finally, I want to replace those lines with value.stringValue() to value.stringValue().value().

I don't know why my current code isn't working?

```
    fileObj = File.new(filepath, "r")
    while (line = fileObj.gets)
    line.scan(/dbg_printf/) do
      line.scan(/value.stringValue()/) do
         if !line.scan(/\.value\(\)/)
           line.gsub!(/value.stringValue()/, 'value.stringValue().value()')
         end
      end
    end
    fileObj.close
```

Comment: Please edit to give an example that shows a file containing a few lines (the fewest and shortest necessary to explain) and what you want the file to look like after the changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primarily, your problem seems to be that you expect altering the string returned from `gets` to alter the contents of the file. There isn't actually that kind of relationship between strings and files. You need to explicitly write the modifications to the file. Personally, I would probably write that code like this:

```
modified_contents = IO.readlines(filepath).map do |line|
  if line =~ /dbg_printf/
    # This regex just checks for value.stringValue() when not followed by .value()
    line.gsub /value\.stringValue\(\)(?!\.value\(\))/, 'value.stringValue().value()'
  else
    line
  end
end
File.open(filepath, 'w') {|file| file.puts modified_contents }
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are not writing the changed lines back to the same file or a new file.  To write them to the same file, read the file into an array, change the array and then write it back to the same or a different file (the later being the more prudent).  Here's one way to do that with few lines of code.

**Code**

`fin_name` and `fout_name` are the names (with paths) of the input and output files, respectively.

```
def filter_array(fin_name, fout_name)
  arr_in = File.readlines(fin_name)
  arr_out = arr_in.map { |l| (l.include?('dbg_printfs') &&
      l.include?('value.stringValue()')                 &&
      !l.include?('value.stringValue().value()')) ? 
    'value.stringValue() to value.stringValue().value()' : l }
  File.open(fout_name, 'w') { |f| f.puts arr_out }
end
```

Because you are reading code files, they will not be so large that reading them all at once into memory will be a problem.

**Example**

First, we'll construct an input file:

```
array = ["My dbg_printfs was a value.stringValue() as well.",
         "Her dbg_printfs was a value.stringValue() but not " +
            "a value.stringValue().value()",
         "value.stringValue() is one of my favorites"]

fin_name  =  'fin'
fout_name =  'fout'
File.open(fin_name, 'w') { |f| f.puts array }
```

We can confirm its contents with:

```
File.readlines(fin_name).map { |l| puts l }
```

Now try it:

```
filter_array(fin_name, fout_name)
```

Read the output file to see if it worked:

```
File.readlines(fout_name).map { |l| puts l }
  #=> value.stringValue() to value.stringValue().value()
  #   Her dbg_printfs was a value.stringValue() but not a value.stringValue().value()
  #   value.stringValue() is one of my favorites
```

It looks OK.

**Explanation**

```
def filter_array(fin_name, fout_name)
  arr_in = File.readlines(fin_name)
  arr_out = arr_in.map { |l| (l.include?('dbg_printfs') &&
      l.include?('value.stringValue()')                 &&
      !l.include?('value.stringValue().value()')) ? 
    'value.stringValue() to value.stringValue().value()' : l }
  File.open(fout_name, 'w') { |f| f.puts arr_out }
end
```

For the above example,

```
arr_in = File.readlines('fin')
  #=> ["My dbg_printfs was a value.stringValue() as well.\n",
  #    "Her dbg_printfs was a value.stringValue() but not a value.stringValue().value()\n",
  #    "value.stringValue() is one of my favorites\n"]
```

The first element of `arr_in` passed to `map` is:

```
l = "My dbg_printfs] was a value.stringValue() as well."
```

We have

```
l.include?('dbg_printfs')                  #=> true
l.include?('value.stringValue()')          #=> true
!l.include?('value.stringValue().value()') #=> true
```

so that element is mapped to:

```
"value.stringValue() to value.stringValue().value()"
```

Neither of the other two elements are replaced by this string, because

```
!l.include?('value.stringValue().value()') #=> false
```

and

```
l.include?('dbg_printfs')                  #=> false
```

respectively.  Hence,

```
arr_out = arr_in.map { |l| (l.include?('dbg_printfs') &&
    l.include?('value.stringValue()')                 &&
    !l.include?('value.stringValue().value()')) ? 
  'value.stringValue() to value.stringValue().value()' : l }
#=> ["value.stringValue() to value.stringValue().value()",
#    "Her dbg_printfs was a value.stringValue() but not a value.stringValue().value()\n",
#    "value.stringValue() is one of my favorites\n"]
```

The final step is writing `arr_out` to the output file.

Comment: It's not writing the array correctly. I mean it writes it in that [ ,.. ,.. ] format which I don't want. I want it to preserve the file as is, with only the minor changes.

Comment: Sorry, you are correct.  After posting I meant to return to test it and give an example, but got tied up.  If you'd like me to add explanation, please let me know.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work for me :\. I don't have time to modify it to work but I appreciate your answer.

Comment: That's odd.  I just retested, cutting and pasting from my answer above and got the same results.